# Can 'happen' mean 'feel'?

Tags: meaning

There was a question
"Is 'Raising a pet can avoid feeling lonely' wrong?"
I thought it was wrong.
Coz the sentence doesn't have me, us or whatever.

So I said
'Raising a pet can help you avoid feeling lonely' is one of the right sentence you can use.

But then a man said 
"'avoid' has a meaning 'To prevent something from happening' so it'll be ok"

So I wondered if happen can mean feel.

Give me your thoughts thanks :)

Comment: "Raising a pet can avoid feeling lonely" is very likely to be a headline on a newspaper article. These are often abbreviated, and formal grammar is, um, relaxed.

Comment: @AndrewLeach The headline would more likely be along the lines of _Raising pet can avoid loneliness_, which, but for the missing article, is completely grammatical. If one uses _raising a pet_ as subject of the sentence, that is absolutely fine. But that subject can not _feel lonely_.

Comment: A more likely newspaper headline would be "Raising a pet can prevent loneliness" or "Avoid loneliness by raising a pet".

Comment: Many comments thanks:) Me and other two men are all Korean. One man wrote the sentence for his English exam and asked if the sentence is right coz the teacher said it's wrong.

Comment: Where would you put "happen" in your sentence?

Answer (score 1):

The sentence "Raising a pet can avoid feeling lonely" makes absolutely no sense in English.  What that sentence essentially means is that "raising a pet" is a person. Because raising a pet can't avoid anything. The person doing the raising can avoid doing something. But without there being some person in the sentence, it makes absolutely no sense in any context.

Comment: I think "makes absolutely no sense" is a bit strong. It's not idiomatic, and it's probably not grammatical, but I can still get the gist of what a learner would be trying to say, to the point where I might rephrase it in a more grammatical way: _Raising a pet can help someone avoid feelings of loneliness._